# jq - select entry if any of several keys is NOT present

Tags: select, filter, jq

I have the JSON file as shown below. What I want - using jq select and display as a new array all the individual Entries where db[].name
is missing any of "Business Overview", "Load Test" or "Performance Monitoring". In other words, any Entry where all three of them are present in db.[] should be dropped and left only these where any of them is missing.

So, the result of applying such a filter would be displaying the very last Entry with "Tenant": "UT-S1835", where db[].name is missing "Load Test".

I can't seem to make it work. You probably know better, would be glad to know how.

Thanks

```
[
  {
    "Entry": {
      "Tenant": "CA-T4932",
      "Stage": "prd"
    },
    "db": [
      {
        "id": "xxxxx0001-0a0a-0b0b-0c0c-765434",
        "name": "Business Overview",
      },
      {
        "id": "bbbb0001-0a0a-0b0b-0c0c-6b68706",
        "name": "Performance Monitoring"
      },
      {
        "id": "bbbb0001-0a0a-0b0b-0c0c-f616465",
        "name": "Load Test"
      }
      ]
  },
  {
    "Entry": {
      "Tenant": "NV-R2133",
      "Stage": "dev"
    },
    "db": [
      {
        "id": "ccccc0006-0a0a-0707-0c0c-765434",
        "name": "Business Overview",
      },
      {
        "id": "rrrrr0007-0f0f-0803-0c0c-5e18331",
        "name": "Performance Monitoring"
      },
      {
        "id": "bbbb0001-0a0a-0b0b-0d0d-d439575",
        "name": "Load Test"
      },
      {
        "id": "zzzz0004-0e0e-0ddd-0a0e-ee83005",
        "name": "Home"
      }
      ]
   },
     {
    "Entry": {
      "Tenant": "UT-S1835",
      "Stage": "stg"
     },
    "db": [
      {
        "id": "bcbcb0032-0ccc-4040-1d1d-326923",
        "name": "Business Overview",
      },
      {
        "id": "rrrrr0007-a3b4-1230-0c0c-0e12044",
        "name": "Performance Monitoring"
      },
      {
        "id": "abab0043-0c0f-0dca-0a0e-ee31705",
        "name": "Home"
      }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: that trivially could be achieved with `jtc` - another powerful JSON processing utility for unix (I'm the developer). If you care, submit another question for `jtc`, where I would be able to help.

Comment: Please fix the putative JSON.  Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for providing these suggestions!.

However, I've released that while the filter of selecting entries with missed keywords does work, the new dilemma is that if multiple keywords missing, from the resulting output it is not clear which of the keyword was missing.

I guess adding a new array Entry.missing ["missing1"="keyword1", "missing2"="kewyord2"] would do the trick, but would this be possible?

Comment: @peak - comma after "Business Overview" was extra, sorry for copypaste, but I can't edit the original post anymore.

Comment: @Invisible999: `["missing1"="keyword1", "missing2"="kewyord2"]` is not valid JSON. Adding new requirements to the question, these many hours after posting the original question is generally not recommended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two solutions which avoid `contains` (which has complex semantics, as noted elsewhere on this page) and `index/1` (which currently is not implemented as efficiently as one would hope).  In both cases, it is assumed that
`$required` has somehow been set to the list of required values, e.g. by:

```
["Business Overview", "Load Test", "Performance Monitoring"] as $required
```

### Simple

```
map(select( $required - [.db[].name] != []))
```

### Efficient

```
map(select( .db as $db
            | all( $required[]; . as $req | any($db[].name; . == $req) )
            | not))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this filter to achieve the result

```
[ "Business Overview", "Load Test", "Performance Monitoring" ] as $bl | 
map( select( [ [.db[].name] | unique[] | IN( $bl[] ) ] |
  map( select( . == true ) ) |
    length == ($bl|length) | not ) 
  )
```

<sup>[jqplay - Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/SOaYKaCjNg)</sup>

The filter works by selecting number of times, unique instances of `.name` field of the object matches one of the entries in the blacklist array. If the count matches the  number of items in blacklist, we exclude that from being printed.

You can also customize the blacklist from the command line by including the array in the `--argjson` field as below and exclude the first line in the above pipeline.

```
--argjson bl '["Business Overview", "Load Test", "Performance Monitoring"]'
```

Comment: Just trying to understand, what is the use of this line 'map( select( . == true )' ?

Comment: @RahulSingh: it would make sense if you try to run the part `["Business Overview", "Load Test", "Performance Monitoring"] as $wl | .[] | [.db[].name | IN($wl[])]` which returns an array of bools indicating which strings had a match with entries in blacklist. Having 3 true values (equaling) the count of matches

Comment: @Inian - thank you, it does work. One follow-up question (see my added comment above) - how would you modify your query to add a new array at the end of Entry to list these keywords which are missing?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach that uses [index](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#index(s),rindex(s)) and [any/2](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#any,any(condition),any(generator;condition)) (the two argument form of any) along with map and select in a manner similar to the other answers given here.

```
  [ "Performance Monitoring", "Business Overview", "Load Test" ] as $required
| map( select( [.db[].name] | any(index($required[]); . == null) ) )
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tZJNb9swDIbv@RWEsEMKRAFlyXayoYdtGLDDvrBmuxg@yBZTeEjk1naydmt/e0Y3dnaYg7ZDS8EQTErvC/LRj8vdDiAB8YWqZVmtrc8JPpa@aMqq8OdiAuLNpi481TV83lK1Lehnm/xQWgcLqhsBKdgaXlR0uSkqcqMbWNuLMdS0orwZQzJ1WZJOvV1TCjdg/fW48I6uxocbSXryCqZwegp@s1qdAK/dLhkB/OYPQLzzTXUtXna/nFiQt77hjHj7Wi7MXAdi0tfOGntObemicuIuebuvCZdxOunO9VqcL1x7/KoNRFQSLVqJGWYSc8xlHIVGm4MBX2hbaa/8O5fuzO3kmEvGMWQSZdEsxmjI5QiX/7ZaRioyUThk9Zdpr97t6ahzup/Ip@/ya6C0HiDiaPsYInkb3EHUdRBj/AxEqjbYhbWXuJQ4Q713CUnNtFbPjcShk87oeRg/EMlR9V8crG4kEhILO9f6kCSaacRB9fcl7wOsDy738/62kGc8qHCAd930M3kY8CznhagDBpDn0qBBqZxyUgfRPNBPDtzqzEgVaNwDR1IBGvOUwG1muSFz96L4bbnc9ki0ih@LZJT@AQ)

Answer (score 0):

The `contains` filter seems suited for your task.

> The filter `contains(b)` will produce true if b is completely contained within the input. … An array B is contained in an array A if all elements in B are contained in any element in A. ([jq 1.6 manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Builtinoperatorsandfunctions))

My solution puts the values of "name" in each object into an array. It uses `contains` to see if the array of the values you listed are all in that array.

```
jq 'map( select( [.db[].name]
   | contains( ["Business Overview", "Performance Monitoring", "Load Test"] )
   | not ) )'
```

**Note**

Inian points out that `contains` can be tricky. For example, this returns "true."

```
jq 'contains(["A"])' <<< '["A B"]'
```

That could lead to the wrong result if the value of "name" is "Business Overview B" and so on.

Comment: The problem with `contains` is that it matches cases when `.name` is like `"Business Overview blabla"` It thinks `"Business Overview"` is present and excludes the object. It does not do a whole string match. Am assuming OP doesn't have cases like that, but you should add a note about that

Comment: @Inian, correct - there could be "Business Overview1" entry but I am looking for only for "Business Overview", so the whole string needs to be matched.